# CodeIgniter error handling

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I'm wondering which way is right to handle the errors in CodeIgniter and specifically the MVC pattern. I'm not talking about only sql errors, but lets say that you have user level-access control system and every level can access specific parts of the site.

What if somebody try to enter in a forbidden place for his level?

Or if you execute a controller based on some conditions and these conditions are not met?

Which is the best way to control the errors without confusing the end user which is browsing and using the application?

I'm wondering how you do it.

Do you use different views and controllers when an error occurs or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking 2 different things.

**First one:**

> but what if you have a form which edits something, but according to user-level you cant edit.

You can achieve this but not showing the fields in the form nor updating the database if the user doesn't have permissions.

```
if ($user_has_permissions)
{
echo form_input('field_name');
echo form_input('field_name');
}
```

and when updating the row

```
if ($user_has_permissions)
{
$this->db->set('db_field_name', $field_name);
}
```

If you want to show an error message in form validation, use callbacks ([callbaks in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)).
Check if the user has permissions and show the message if hasn't.

**Second one**

> Using die() is not an option, I just dont wanna crash my whole app

If you wan't to stop the execution without using die(), you have some other "friendlier" forms to do it:

```
show_404();
show_error();
show_error('Description of your error');
```

This will stop the execution and will show a fancy screen with the error description.

Comment: This is kinda what I mean. But a slight different. I was writing PHP applications in procedure style like 3-4 years and for a couple of months I'm trying to get deep into the MVC and OOP and sometimes a stupid questions like this come in my mind. :D As I know there is no logic code allowed in the view except if it is for showing something according some user and view conditions. I can hide links which this user's level cannot see, but how can I stop the whole controller to be executed? wrapping it with a if($user_level... seems a little bit lame to me. So I'm looking for the right practice :)

Comment: If you don't want the whole controller to be executed, use show_error('No permission message') *at the constructor*.

Comment: I use another approach. I have a model that returns if the user has permissions. If hasn't, I redirect to a controller showing header, footer, titles, etc. but instead of loading the view, I load I view with a big icon saying: "You are not allowed to be here".

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the user's access level in your database. If a user tries to access a forbidden place you could store some error in the userdata and display them in the view if its set.

The codeigniter session class documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) No, I meant different thing. The implementation of the user-level system is not the problem for me. The problem is when an exception occurs. I dont know which is the right way for displaying errors. Using `die()` is not an option, I just dont wanna crash my whole app. If you have a form its easy you have form_validation and you can display the errors for each field specificly, but what if you have a form which edits something, but according to user-level you cant edit. How to display the error? Maybe a different views for errors?

Comment: You could create a access denied view telling the user whats up. And then pass a link to the view for them to go back to where they came from.

Comment: I think you're better off using javascript or jquery to display errors if they try to change info they aren't allowed to. You could for example send an ajax request to a function with the current field. the function can check the database for the user's level which is stored in the session. You could have the fields in your database together with the minimum user level needed. if its any less you can throw the exception.

Comment: AJAX was the first thing that came to my mind, but is not enough. Now I'm hiding the links to the forbidden places, but what if somebody try to find vulnerability? I want extra security. I think that extra controller and view for errors will do the work. I don't wanna mess up with the "clean" page view.

Comment: I'm thinking for something like that:
User loads `articles/edit/1`.
I write a global method for checking the user-level which takes for parameter the user level required to access the page.
When edit method is called he calls the `user-level` check method and it checks for meeting the requirements.
If everything is okay the `edit` method continues the execute, but if something is wrong with the levels the `level-access` method loads an error view and displays the current error. Is this solutions good?

Comment: What do you mean with hiding the link? do you check server or client side? to be honest, i think you're better off by just checking the userlevel server-side and just not giving certain user-levels the posibility to edit certain information. If you do this server-side people wont be able to pass the check by for example turning off javascript. btw sorry for the hold up

Comment: Example: I have a link on the page "Edit". I check if the user has the needed level and if it passes, I print it, if not I dont. But this is not enough I have to make a check in the whole controller if somebody access it manualy in the URL.

Comment: Im hoping you check for if the visiter is logged in inside of you controller. you could just check for the users premissions inside of the edit function and put the rest of your code inside of there. If the visiter has no premission then you can redirect and load your error view.

Comment: Here is some example code from me http://pastebin.com/ZRYXDY8F So as you see I check for login in the constructor, but in the current class all the methods can be accessed only if you are logged, but in some no user level will be required. I'm thinking if I should wrap the inside of the controller with userlevel check or I should I just use `show_error()` ?

Comment: This is what i came up with http://pastebin.com/index/ZRYXDY8F